# Greenmail WebApp server API

Tags: mail-server, greenmail

i want to use greenmail as a webapp.
is there a way in java to dynamically create user accounts on the greenmail server?

javamail does not contain api for creating users on mail server.
is there a rest i can use or anything in java code for dynamically create user accounts on the greenmail server?

really need help here.

Thanks!

Comment: OK i know how to create an account dynamically. but know i need to know how to delete the account :)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/greenmail-mail-test/greenmail/issues/80 (available in next release > 1.4.1):

You can delete a user via

```
greenMail.getManagers().getUserManager().deleteUser(user);
```

Comment: Thanks, This can not be used when using greenmail as a webapp. There is no instance of the greenmail at the java code when running greenmail as a webapp. The way to create users dynamically is by sending an email to a user that does not exist, greenmail automatically creates the user. But I don't know how to delete the user that was created. Is there a way to to retrieve the instance of the web app?

Comment: Or a way to send a request to the server to delete a user?